# Java: Compare elements of 2D array(matrix) in the column And finding row number containing smallest value in that column

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, 2d

I have an array matrix with n rows and s columns. I need to find the row number for each column containing smallest element. for example I have array matrix

```
double[][]={{2, 3, 4, 6}, 
            {3, 6, 7.0, 3.3}, 
            {2.1, 3.4, 2, 7.7}
           };
```

Here I expect 0, 0, 2, 3. Because In first column smallest element is in first row, In second column smallest element is in first row, for third smallest no is in third row and for forth column smallest element is in second row.
How can I achieve this in java code

Comment: *In second column smallest element is in 0th row, for third smallest no is in third row and so on* where is the row with index 3?

Comment: @nullpointer third, I  mean row with index 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think you are confused about row and column of an array. Your array has 3 rows and 4 columns. I will assume you want to find the column index of smallest element of each row. If so, find below code:

```
        double arr[][] = {{2, 3, 4, 6},
                {3, 6, 7.0, 3.3},
                {2.1, 3.4, 2, 7.7}
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int column = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            column = (arr[i][column] < arr[i][j]) ? column : j;
        }
        System.out.println("Smallest element for row " + i + " = " + column +" th column");
    }
```

Hope this helps ;)

Updated one(to find row number):

```
double arr[][] = {{2, 3, 4, 6},
                {3, 6, 7.0, 3.3},
                {2.1, 3.4, 2, 7.7}
        };


        for(int j=0;j<arr[0].length;j++)
        {
            int row = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
                row = (arr[row][j] < arr[i][j]) ? row : i;
            }
            System.out.println("Column = " + j + " Row = " + row);
        }
```

Comment: You have done wrong assumption sir. I'm looking for row index for the smallest number in column.

Answer (score 0):

Loops.

I'd solve this problem with a nested loop.
As this seems to be a *gimme the codes* question I'll provide you with the pseudo code to help with your problem, for you to implement.

```
double mat[][]={{...},{...}}//declare your 2d array

//loop through each row
for (int i=0;i<mat.length;i++)//note mat.length is number of rows
{

   int min_j=0;//for each row reset the lowest column index
   //loop through each column
   for (int j=0;j<mat[i].length;j++)//note mat[i].length is number of cols for row i
   {
      //check if this column has the lowest value
      if(mat[i][j]<mat[i][min_j])
      {
        min_j=j;//set the new lowest index
      }
   }
   //print the index of the column with the lowest value for each row
   print(min_j+',');

}
```

Hopefully this is a good place to start. You didn't indicate if you want to print the values out, or store them in a different array so that's left as an exercise.

you've indicated in the comments that you want the lowest value per row instead of column.
The code for it:

```
double mat[][]={{...},{...}}//declare your 2d array

//loop through each column
for (int i=0;i<mat[i].length;i++)//note mat[i].length is number of columns in row i
{

   int min_j=0;//for each column reset the lowest row index
   //loop through each row
   for (int j=0;j<mat.length;j++)
   {
      //check if this row has the lowest value
      if(mat[j][i]<mat[min_j][i])
      {
        min_j=j;//set the new lowest index
      }
   }
   //print the index of the row with the lowest value for each column
   print(min_j+',');

}
```

Comment: Have a look at if statement where you have compared same values. Is that a mistake. I got messed that may be trick. If that is trick please elaborate to explain bit.

Comment: Yes, I apologize, meant to compare with min_j, fixed now

Comment: Outer loop should be for each column.

Comment: @log, I've amended to answer that case

Answer (score 0):

I did some modifications, how about this:

```
    class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double twoDArr[][] = {
            {2, 3, 4, 6}, 
            {3, 6, 7, 3.3}, 
            {2.1, 3.4, 2, 7.7}
        };

        int row = 0;
        for(double element[] : twoDArr){

            int index = 0;
            double auxNum = 999999999.0;
            for(int i = 0; i < element.length; i++){
                if(element[i] < auxNum){
                    auxNum = element[i];
                    index = i;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("row: "+ row + " Smallest: " + auxNum + " Index: " + index);
            row++;
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

```
row: 0 Smallest: 2.0 Index: 0
row: 1 Smallest: 3.0 Index: 0
row: 2 Smallest: 2.0 Index: 2
```

Comment: Here you are printing the value of i'th column. He wants the index of the column.

Comment: Sorry Sir It do not meet expected Output. For every column there must be a row containing smallest number of that column.

Comment: I modified the original code. Is this what you wanted?